# Proguard error when -optimizationpasses is above 2

Tags: android, eclipse, optimization, proguard

**EDIT:**

This is caused by old Proguard version(4.7) . Doesn't happen anymore with 5.2

---

I use Proguard (in eclipse) to optimize and obfuscate my Android project, but something odd is happening. When I set *-optimizationpasses* to 1 or 2, it's OK, but when **I set 3 or above, I got this error**:

> Conversion to Dalvik Format failed with error 1

In Eclipse's Error Log View, I have found the entry 'Conversion to Dalvik Format failed with error 1': it contains this stack trace

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:317)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:313)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:238)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:825)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:274)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:313)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:238)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Here is the Proguard config excerpt concerning optimization:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
#-optimizationpasses 3 or above -> exception
-optimizationpasses 2
#-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
```

**Question:**

- Why is that Proguard cause an error when -optimizationpasses is above
  2? (especially since android default setting is 5 (in sdk 23 / M)
- How / Where can I find more details about the root cause of this
  problem and, possibly, report a bug to Proguard team?

Thanks for helping

Comment: try updating proguard to latest version

Comment: I am using very latest Android SDK. Do you mean it's not  enough and I have to 'patch' the Android sdk with latest Proguard?

Comment: i am asking about proguard version

Comment: 4.7 I can't believe that! How is that Proguard version is not updated when  ADT.. well, I'll update (to 5.2) and send some feedback here. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @ankitagrawal : Upgrading to Proguard 5.2 fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update to Latest Release of Proguard i.e from 4.7 to 5.2

That should fix the issue.

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks a lot ankitagrawal :-)